# LNK1112 module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64' (VC++ 2005)

Tags: visual-c++, 64-bit, visual-c++-2005

I am trying to build a blank, 64-bit C++ application in Visual Studio 2005 Professional using these steps:

1. Create a new Win32 Console Application project
2. Go to Configuration Manager, create new Solution Platform of type x64, copy settings from Win32
3. Save & build

However, I get this error:

`LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'`

So, I tried updating the library directories to point to `kernel32.lib`:

1. Go to Project Properties, Linker, General, Additional Library Directories and set
   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\lib\amd64"
2. Save & build

This gives me the error:

`LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'user32.lib'`

So, I tried updating the library directories to point to `user32.lib`:

1. Go to Project Properties, Linker, General, Additional Library Directories and add
   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib\x64"
2. Save & build

But now I am getting the error:

`.\x64\debug\stdafx.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'`

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Something is pretty broken in your setup.  Sounds to me you've been copying directories to try to fix an earlier problem.  Which got possibly started because the VS2005 setup program doesn't install the 64-bit compilers.

Comment: @Hans I haven't copied any directories, and VS2005 does give you the option to install the 64-bit compilers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246588(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must've been a broken installation of Visual Studio. A new installation of Windows and VS2005 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem is with the object file `stdafx.obj` rather than the system libraries. The warning is saying that `stdafx.obj` is 32-bit so it can't link into a 64-bit target. Things to try:

- Delete the build directories `x64` and `win32`
- Rebuild the project
- Check the build settings for `stdafx.cpp` to ensure it's building as 64-bit

Comment: @mandrill What setting should I be checking? I can't see anything about 64-bit in stdafx.cpp properties.

Answer (score 0):

Its been long since the question was asked, but for the benefit of others who happen to read this, the change required is in the linker flag setting. Change /machine:I386 to /machine:x64